# Which table was updated by the last query?

Tags: mysql, update

When I perform an update query, MySQL server gives me information about how many rows were updated. But I wish to know in which table they were updated.
Is that information somewhere available?

The query is something like

```
UPDATE t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.a=t2.b
SET t1.x=1, t2.y=t1.z
WHERE ....
```

8 rows affected...

But in which table? t1 or t2?

Comment: Or maybe both tables combined?  I guess that if you need the info, you would perform `SELECT(s)` beforehand to see how many rows will be updated.